# Зачем в C/C++ объявление отделено от определения?

Tags: c++, c, компиляция

То что из этого факта вытекает выделение объявлений в отдельные .h файлы со всеми их плюсами и недостатками это мне понятно, но зачем введено обязательное объявление перед использованием (определением) переменной (функции, структуры)?

Comment: Отделение объявления от определения - это фундаментальный принцип языков программирования C и C++. Это связано с тем, что компилятору необходимо знать тип и размер переменной, функции или структуры, прежде чем использовать ее в коде. Объявления позволяют задать типы исходных данных, используемые в программе, а определения указывают, как эти данные будут использоваться.

Comment: Потому что без объявления никакие программные сущности использовать невозможно. Например, вы хотите сложить два числа типа float. Допустим, они определены в другом С-файле, а в текущем не объявлены. Сложение целых чисел и чисел с плавающей точкой выполняется разными машинными инструкциями. Не зная типа этих чисел, компилятор не сможет определить, какие именно инструкции необходимо использовать для сложения этих чисел.

Comment: это не обязательно - у вас вопрос ложный

Comment: Объявление нужно только если вызов находится в одном файле, а определение в другом.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Объявление может понадобится и если все в одном файле, например если две функции вызывают друг друга.

Answer (score 2):

Это не обязательно. Но при циклических зависимостях и проектах с большим количеством исходных файлов или библиотек оно нужно.

Объявление переменной в заголовках с приставкой `extern` означает, что переменная известна и она находится где-то.

h.h :

```cpp
extern int glob ;
```

a.cpp :

```cpp
# include "h.h"
...
++ glob ;
...
```

b.cpp :

```cpp
# include "h.h"
int glob = 0 ;
```

Без предварительного объявления в `a.cpp` произойдёт ошибка неизвестной переменной с неизвестным типом.

Предварительное объявление функции уже надо при задаче, использующей рекурсию.

```
funA(x) := funA(x/2) + funB(x/2) или 0
funB(x) := funA(x/2) - funB(x/2) или 0
```

Без предварительного объявления эти функции не скомпилируются.

```cpp
int funB ( int ) ; // надо

int funA ( int x ) {
  if ( x )
    return funA ( x / 2 ) + funB ( x / 2 ) ;
  return 0 ;
}

int funB ( int x ) {
  if ( x )
    return funA ( x / 2 ) - funB ( x / 2 ) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

А если они находятся в разных `.cpp` файлах то **обе** эти функции надо предварительно объявлять, так как один файл должен знать о существовании другого.

Предварительное объявление структуры уже надо, чтобы компилятор  знал о её размере в байтах. И при сборке например массива структур можно было выделить для них чёткое место в памяти.

```cpp
struct S ; // предварительное объявление только типа

struct S Arr [ 2 ] ; // ошибка - неизвестен размер

struct S {
  double d ;
  float f ;
} ;
```

Ну и точно так-же если разные переменные находятся в разных `.cpp` файлах то **обе** эти переменные должны знать о размере структуры и её надо **полностью** объявлять в заголовочном файле.